# Is there a relation between $ (x_1^TAx_1 +x_2^TAx_2)$ and $(x_1^TAx_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a relation between $ (x_1^TAx_1 +x_2^TAx_2)$ and $(x_1^TAx_2)$?

$A$: $nxn$ positive semi-definite matrix.

$x_1 \in R^n ,x \neq 0$

$x_2 \in R^n ,x \neq 0$

Comment: If $A$ is not symmetric then you cannot hope to find a relation. Notice that if a relation could be obtained then it would be symmetric in $x_1,x_2$ which means that $x_1^T A x_2 = x_2^T A x_1$.

Comment: $S$ is symmetric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, then you can always say that
$$2x_1^TAx_2\le x_1^TAx_1 +x_2^TAx_2.$$

This is a direct corollary of $A$ being symmetric positive semidefinite; apply the definition to the vector $(x_1-x_2)$.